How to access GoogleMap() onMapCreated in another class using GetX? The animateCamera didn't work
This is the scenario I have been facing
Based on the code below (sorry I just copied all my code so that I can understand the answers well), I wanted to animate my Google Map screen from the current location to the new point or location using GetX state management.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class GoogleMapPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const GoogleMapPage({super.key});

  static const LatLng googlePlex = LatLng(8.242876, 124.243513);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Map'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[50],
      ),
      body: GoogleMapView(
        onMapCreated: (controller) {
          // Handle map created event if needed
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () async {
          Position position = await _determinedPosition();
          final GoogleMapController googleMapController =
              Get.find<GoogleMapController>();
          googleMapController.markers.clear();
          googleMapController.markers.add(
            Marker(
              markerId: const MarkerId('currentLocation'),
              position: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude),
            ),
          );
          googleMapController.animateCamera(
            CameraUpdate.newLatLngZoom(
              LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude),
              17,
            ),
          );
        },
        label: const Text('Current Location'),
        elevation: 0.0,
        icon: const Icon(Icons.location_history),
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(250, 133, 20, 26),
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28.0),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    );
  }

  Future<Position> _determinedPosition() async {
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;

    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();

    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      throw 'Location services are disabled';
    }

    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();

    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();

      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        throw 'Location permission denied';
      }
    }

    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      throw 'Location permissions are permanently denied';
    }
    return Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
  }
}

class GoogleMapController extends GetxController {
  final CameraPosition initialCameraPosition = const CameraPosition(
    target: GoogleMapPage.googlePlex,
    zoom: 17,
  );

  final Set<Marker> markers = {
    const Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId('sourceLocation'),
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
      position: GoogleMapPage.googlePlex,
    ),
  };

  var mapType = Rx<MapType>(MapType.normal);

  final Rx<LatLng> _currentLocation = Rx<LatLng>(GoogleMapPage.googlePlex);
  LatLng get currentLocation => _currentLocation.value;

  void updateMapPosition(LatLng position) {
    _currentLocation.value = position;
  }
}

class GoogleMapView extends StatelessWidget {
  final void Function(GoogleMapController)? onMapCreated;

  const GoogleMapView({super.key, this.onMapCreated});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<GoogleMapController>(
      init: GoogleMapController(),
      builder: (controller) {
        return GoogleMap(
          initialCameraPosition: controller.initialCameraPosition,
          markers: controller.markers,
          zoomControlsEnabled: false,
          onMapCreated: onMapCreated != null
              ? (controller) => onMapCreated!(controller as GoogleMapController)
              : null,
          onTap: (position) {
            // Handle tap events if needed
          },
          mapType: controller.mapType.value,
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
          compassEnabled: true,
          trafficEnabled: false,
          buildingsEnabled: true,
          mapToolbarEnabled: true,
          rotateGesturesEnabled: true,
          scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
          tiltGesturesEnabled: true,
          zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class GoogleMapBinding extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut<GoogleMapController>(() => GoogleMapController());
  }
}


How to animate Google Map screen position from one point to another using GetX state management in Flutter.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please elaborate more as to what you mean by "The animateCamera didn't work"? If you can provide some kind of errors, debugging details, and etc. would greatly help the community in assisting you with your issue. Please read how to ask and how to provide a minimal reproducible example to improve your chances of getting help.

Hi, sorry for my question being unclear. I tried the google_maps_flutter package for my app using this code link but I used GetX for my state management (code above). The problem is that my screen will not animate to the new location.
